# Mongodb Mac install

Tags: database, mongodb, installation, nosql, frontend

I am trying to download mongodb for my macbook, and keep getting this error. My computer is fully updated. Below is more context on what i have been doing, following the mongodb instructions from their website.

Lauryns-MacBook-Air:~ laurynmills$ mongod --config /usr/local/etc/mongod.conf --fork
dyld: Symbol not found: _syslog$DARWIN_EXTSN
Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/mongod (which was built for Mac OS X 10.13)
Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
in /usr/local/bin/mongod
Abort trap: 6

```html
Lauryns-MacBook-Air:~ laurynmills$ brew install mongodb-community@4.4
Warning: mongodb/brew/mongodb-community 4.4.0 is already installed and up-to-date
To reinstall 4.4.0, run `brew reinstall mongodb-community`
Lauryns-MacBook-Air:~ laurynmills$ brew services start mongodb-community@4.4
Service `mongodb-community` already started, use `brew services restart mongodb-community` to restart.
Lauryns-MacBook-Air:~ laurynmills$ mongod --config /usr/local/etc/mongod.conf --fork
dyld: Symbol not found: _syslog$DARWIN_EXTSN
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/mongod (which was built for Mac OS X 10.13)
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
 in /usr/local/bin/mongod
Abort trap: 6
Lauryns-MacBook-Air:~ laurynmills$ brew services stop mongodb-community@4.4
Stopping `mongodb-community`... (might take a while)
==> Successfully stopped `mongodb-community` (label: homebrew.mxcl.mongodb-commu
Lauryns-MacBook-Air:~ laurynmills$ mongod --config /usr/local/etc/mongod.conf --fork
dyld: Symbol not found: _syslog$DARWIN_EXTSN
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/mongod (which was built for Mac OS X 10.13)
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
 in /usr/local/bin/mongod
Abort trap: 6
Lauryns-MacBook-Air:~ laurynmills$ brew services start mongodb-community@4.4
==> Successfully started `mongodb-community` (label: homebrew.mxcl.mongodb-commu
Lauryns-MacBook-Air:~ laurynmills$ ps aux | grep -v grep | grep mongod
Lauryns-MacBook-Air:~ laurynmills$ mongo
dyld: Symbol not found: _syslog$DARWIN_EXTSN
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/mongo (which was built for Mac OS X 10.13)
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
 in /usr/local/bin/mongo
Abort trap: 6
Lauryns-MacBook-Air:~ laurynmills$ mongod
dyld: Symbol not found: _syslog$DARWIN_EXTSN
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/mongod (which was built for Mac OS X 10.13)
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
 in /usr/local/bin/mongod
Abort trap: 6
Lauryns-MacBook-Air:~ laurynmills$
```

Comment: I've the same problem on Mac OS 10.12. What's your OS and Xcode version?